# Unable to display all the elements of an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Menu driven program for adding and displaying employee details.
Taking input from the user for employee details.
Store it into array list and display it.

I have added the entries to a list but always the last entered data replaces all the elements in the list.
Taking input in switch case 1 and add it to an arraylist and displaying it in another case:

```
    class Employee
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int empid,n;

        String empname, empdesignation, empdept, empproject;
        public Employee() { }

        public Employee(int id,String name,String desig,String dept,String proj)
        {
            this.empid=id;
            this.empname=name;
            this.empdesignation=desig;
            this.empdept=dept;
            this.empproject=proj;
        }

    public void setEmpNo() {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of employees: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public int getEmpNo() {
        return n;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return empid;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this.empid = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return empname;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.empname = name;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return empdept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.empdept = dept;
    }

    public String getDesig() {
        return empdesignation;
    }

    public void setDesig(String desig) {
        this.empdesignation = desig;
    }

    public String getProject() {
        return empproject;
    }

    public void setProject(String proj) {
        this.empproject = proj;
    }

    public void displayemp(int id, String name, 
                           String dept, String designation, String project)
    {
        System.out.print("\n============================================================\n");
        System.out.println("ID: " + id);
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Department: " + dept);
        System.out.println("Designation: " + designation);
        System.out.println("Project: " + project);
        System.out.print("\n============================================================\n");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class trying
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int ch = 0, id, n, abc, count = 0, pcount = 0;
        final int  maxEmp=1000;

        String name, designation, dept, pname, mgrname, project;

        Employee emp5 = new Employee();

        Project proj5 = new Project();
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        List<Project> list1 = new ArrayList<Project>();

        switch (ch) {
            case 1:
                emp5.setEmpNo();
                int a = emp5.getEmpNo();

                for (int i = 1; i < a+1; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter ID: ");

                    id = sc.nextInt();
                    emp5.setID(id);
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");

                    name = sc.nextLine();
                    emp5.setName(name);
                    System.out.print("Enter Department: ");

                    dept = sc.nextLine();
                    emp5.setDept(dept);
                    System.out.print("Enter Designation: ");

                    designation = sc.nextLine();
                    emp5.setDesig(designation);
                    System.out.print("Enter Project: ");

                    project = sc.nextLine();
                    emp5.setProject(project);
                    list.add(emp5);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Showing Employee Details:");
                for(Employee e:list)
                {
                System.out.println(e.empid+" "+e.empname+" "+e.empdept+" "
                                   +e.empdesignation+" "+e.empproject);
                }
                break;
        }
    } while (!(ch <= 0 || ch > 7));
}
```

I need to display all the entries of the array list, but the last entered data get repeatedly displayed.

Comment: so it's either a problem in entering the data, or in displaying it. what is the exact method you are talking about?

Comment: What use case is the while loop at the and of sencond class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Employee emp5 = new Employee();
```

This will fo inside the for loop after :

```
for (int i = 1; i < a+1; i++) {
    Employee emp5 = new Employee();

    ....
}
```

You will have to create new employee obj. At this moment you are keep updating same obj.

> Update

Try creating new obj after adding item in the list

```
list.add(emp5);
emp5 = new Employee();
```

Comment: if Employee emp5 = new Employee(); goes inside the for loop then I won't be able to access emp5 in another switch case since it becomes local to that switch case

Comment: @VedanthVinay please mark it as answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark my answer as 'Accepted'